# ¿Como evitar el postback o regreso a una ventana cuando cierro sesión?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Espero me puedan apoyar, hice una aplicación web en net core 6, coloqué mi método para cerrar sesión, funciona muy bien! pero  la hora de dar clic en la flecha de retroceder en el navegador, puede entrar de nuevo al sistema y no eh podido encontrar algo que me ayude, como puedo hacer que ya no vuelva ingresar cuando cerré sesión?.

en mi controlador tengo esto:

```
public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

Y en mi vista solo lo mando a llamar de esta manera en una etiqueta li:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Main" asp-action="Logout">Cerrar Sesión</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Y ¿Cómo haces tu llamada al Cierre de sesión? ¿Qué versión de ASP.NET? Necesitamos más detalles para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Debes navegar a la primera página desde la página de LogOut, así se borra el historial de navegación.

```
<script>
    var inicial = (window.history.length - 1)* -1;
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.history.go(inicial);
    }, "1000");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que existe un caché llamada [bfcache](https://web.dev/bfcache/) que guarda las páginas que están en la pila de navegación, de esta manera al ir hacia adelante o hacia atrás no hace un llamado al servidor sino que muestra la página almacenada en dicho caché, por este motivo te muestra un contenido aun cuando tu hayas hecho logout.

Una posible solución es usar el evento [pageshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) para detectar mediante el atributo [persisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PageTransitionEvent/persisted) si la página está en caché o no, y si lo está obligar a hacer un reload

```
window.addEventListener( "pageshow", function ( event ) {
  if ( event.persisted ) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```