# ¿Como evitar que cuando lede al boton de atras ya no se muestre una vista al cerrar session en laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

Buen dia, estoy haciendo un sistema en laravel, pero tengo un problema por ejemplo si estoy en el home y cierro session este me redirigue al login pero si le doy atras (con el boton del navegador) me regresa al home (ya no cargan los datos por que no hay session activa pero se muestra la vista) cuando quiero que se rediriga al login.

las rutas ya tiene el Middleware de "auth" es decir que checa si esta autentificado.

no se si esto se hace con php o con js.

Seria

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Cuando tu sistema entra a `home`, detectas si hay sesión activa, si es el caso, no haces nada, pero si no es el caso, haces una redirección hacia `login`.

Comment: Lee esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/571046/301324

Comment: Yussef muchas gracias, cheque la pregunta y si era la solucion. Gracias!! @Yussef