# ¿Como restringir paginas cuando limpias una sesion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Espero me puedan ayudar, estoy realizando una aplicación en net core en la cual tengo mi metodo login:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string correo, string contrasena)
    {
        if (correo == null || contrasena == null)
        {
            TempData["mensajeError"] = "No puede ir ningún campo vacío.";
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        try
        {
            contrasena = usuarioRepositorio.EncriptarPassword(contrasena);

            var usuario = await usuarioRepositorio.ObtenerUsuario(correo, contrasena);

            if(usuario == null)
            {
                TempData["mensajeError"] = "Error con las credenciales ingresadas, intenta de nuevo.";
                return View();
            }else if(usuario != null)
            {
                List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, usuario.Nombre),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, usuario.Correo)
                };

                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                AuthenticationProperties properties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), properties);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["mensajeError"] = ex.ToString();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
```

Este es mi método `CerrarSesion`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CerrarSesion()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Autenticacion");
    }
```

Cuando doy clic en el botón de cerrar sesión, me limpia correctamente la sesion y elimina mi cookie, pero si le doy en la flecha de regresar sigue entrando, hasta que le doy refrescar a la página es cuando se sale. ¿Como puedo hacer que eso no pase?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como evitar el postback o regreso a una ventana cuando cierro sesión?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/570988/como-evitar-el-postback-o-regreso-a-una-ventana-cuando-cierro-sesi%c3%b3n)

Comment: Ya lo implemente y sigue dejandome entrar cuando regreso a la página anterior, hasta que vuelvo a refrescar la página me funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento que estás experimentando se debe a la caché del navegador. Cuando presionas la flecha de regresar, el navegador muestra la página almacenada en caché en lugar de hacer una nueva solicitud al servidor.
Para evitar que esto suceda, puedes agregar una directiva de caché en el encabezado de la respuesta del método CerrarSesion para indicar al navegador que no almacene en caché la página. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CerrarSesion()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
    
    // Agregar directiva de no almacenar en caché
    Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");
    
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Autenticacion");
}
```

Al agregar estas directivas de caché, le estás indicando al navegador que no almacene en caché la página y que siempre solicite una nueva versión al servidor.
Con esto, cuando el usuario presione la flecha de regresar, el navegador realizará una nueva solicitud al servidor en lugar de mostrar la página almacenada en caché, y el usuario será redirigido correctamente a la página de inicio de sesión.

Comment: Investigando el método que pusiste @PabloXD, es viejo y actualmente para las versiones nuevas de net core ya no es funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Se resolvió de la siguiente manera:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CerrarSesion()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
        {
            var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));
            foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
            }
        }

        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Autenticacion");
    }
```

Aqui solo aumento la parte de contar las cookies que estan guardadas y las elimino una por una y luego limpio la sesión.
Espero que alguíen le puedo servir